# spring-restdocs How to remove the table name from the path parameters

Tags: spring-restdocs

I am documenting the path parameters for my api. But it displays some auto generated table name.
I am trying to remove the table name from the path parameter . I didn't succeed.

Please help me out.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p4o1.png)

Comment: You want to remove "Table 2" and keep "/v1/residences/{id}"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove only "Table 2" part of table caption, you can try to add caption block with empty title. For example:

```
[caption=]
./v1/residences/{id}
include::{snippets}/index/request-parameters.adoc[]
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to combine the answers of @jmformenti and @alek:

1. Create a file `path-parameters.snippet` inside `src/test/resources/org/springframework/restdocs/templates/asciidoctor/`
2. Use this template content:

```
[caption=]
.{{path}}
|===
|Parameter|Description

{{#parameters}}
|{{#tableCellContent}}`+{{name}}+`{{/tableCellContent}}
|{{#tableCellContent}}{{description}}{{/tableCellContent}}

{{/parameters}}
|===
```

Now, all generated `path-parameters.adoc` files will have the proper contents and you don't need to add it for every include like in the answer of Alek.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [customize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-customizing-snippets) the path-parameters snippet:

1. Add new snippet template in your project *src/test/resources/org/springframework/restdocs/templates/asciidoctor/path-parameters.snippet*
2. Template content:

```
+{{path}}+
|===
|Parameter|Description

{{#parameters}}
|{{#tableCellContent}}`+{{name}}+`{{/tableCellContent}}
|{{#tableCellContent}}{{description}}{{/tableCellContent}}

{{/parameters}}
|===
```